# Grit's clone method is undefined?

Tags: ruby, git, git-clone, grit

I've recently started working on a project that uses git for storage and ruby as a front-end. The first version of my script used ruby-git, which was ok though pretty simple. When I needed to do more specific work with my commits and logs it was recommended that I move to grit. However, I've a road block early on- grit seems incapable of cloning remote repositories. All examples I've found using the Repository class create a local repository and searching through the source I've found Grit's clone method is undefined. What gives?

This is my first StackOverflow question, so thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since Git is well structured, Grit uses a method missing (Grit::Git#method_missing) to 'systematically' execute Git commands.

See link below for an example that should help you.

https://gist.github.com/731502

Comment: Yes, thank you. & Double thanks for the tip about the clone bug.